# How Can We get the Values of the Form without Post in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Have Make a Create Form.
& I want the Values in Controller how can I get them Without Postback the Whole Page?
Any article please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use AJAX to send the form values to a controller action. The [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin is very good for this purpose. The plugin reads all the form values and sends them in an AJAX request to a controller action for processing.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to call a web service (i.e ajax).  Check out [this](http://www.nikhilk.net/Ajax-MVC.aspx) article for some basics.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the "postback" term I think you might be coming from a WebForms background which hides all the `HTTP` request-response cycle. `POST`s are done on `<form>`s, so technically the entire page is not "posted back", but the data from the form in which the pressed  resides.